# Capacity of Asyncstorage React-native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

What will be maximum Storage Capacity of the Async Storage in React-native for both Android and IOS?

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=Capacity+of+Asyncstorage+React-native

Answer (score 4, accepted):

6MB On Android, 
but you can still increase Asyncstorage.

Follow link given below to increase Asyncstorage(Android)--->

https://codedaily.io/tutorials/4/Increase-Android-AsyncStorage-Size-in-React-Native

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: what about ios?

Comment: ios unlimited, we only got the issue in android with 6M limited